# How to remove advanced tab from CKEditor - WYSIWYG

Tags: php, javascript, wysiwyg

The wysiwyg-editor from http://CKEditor.com has too many buttons and is cluttored for many users. so I decided to remove unnecessary tabs and button. So I would like to remove the Advanced tab from the image uploader. Any suggestion how to do it?

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, as of this writing, that site is down.

Comment: @Cgraphics If my answer below solved your issue, please accept it by clicking the outlined checkmark below the down arrow.

Comment: no unfortunately did not work :(

Comment: 'Did not work' is not a problem description; what happened?  Did you not try the second option?  Please add the code of your entire config setting.

Comment: @Cgraphics I've updated my answer with the working code.  It turns out that the config option is case-sensitive, and I got the original option just slightly wrong.. I've fixed it thus.  It is a lower case `a`, for `advanced` versus upper case.

Comment: It's also possible to remove unnecessary elements from the tabs that you keep and to add explanatory text where needed.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It appears there are two methods of doing this;

1: Edit your CKEditor config definition(config.js):

```js
config.removeDialogTabs = 'image:advanced';
```

Remember; the config setting is case-sensitive.

2: You can of course also do this in-line so you can refer to it by editor:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor_kama',
{  //                  ^---Editor Id goes here
    removeDialogTabs : 'image:advanced'
});
```

Comment: The following document can also be referred to(and should be), for more in-depth information regarding [setting your config](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Setting_Configurations).

Comment: Thank you. I have asked another question and wondering if you know the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12664618/in-ckeditor-wysiwyg-how-to-change-the-icon-of-image-upload-button

Comment: If you need to do it to multiple dialogs, this config option uses a  semicolons for a seperator, not commas like other options! `config.removeDialogTabs = 'image:advanced;image:advanced';`

Comment: If you want to remove both the "advanced" and the "Link" tab you have to use: `config.removeDialogTabs = 'image:Link;image:advanced';` notice the uppercase "Link" and the semicolon seperator.

Answer (score 2):

Try this in **plugins/images/dialog/image.js**

```
id : 'advanced',
               label : editor.lang.common.advancedTab,
               hidden : true,
               elements :
```

Adding the hidden : true should work. 
Or you could try:

```
yourDialogDefinition.getContents('advanced').hidden=true;
```

Comment: it's much better to use the removeDialogTabs config option as that will make upgrades easier

Answer (score 2):

It appears that `config.removeDialogTabs = 'image:advanced';` does not work anymore - or at least it did not work for me. [But there are instructions if the official documentation on how to edit dialogs](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_howtos_dialog_windows). Based on those instructions, I use this solution:

```
CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function (ev) {
    var dialogName = ev.data.name,
    dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;

    if (dialogName === 'image') {
        dialogDefinition.removeContents('advanced');
        dialogDefinition.removeContents('link');
    }
});
```

Comment: the config.removeDialogTabs is not working for me either anymore. used this and worked great.

Answer (score 1):

Since the removeDialogTabs  doesn't work anymore, the latest way of hiding the tab is simply:

```
linkShowAdvancedTab = false
```

in the config.
This works in version 4.13 at least.

Comment: linkShowTargetTab works too. But linkShowUploadTab does not work